# RTSP on phonegap not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cordova, phonegap-cli

I am not able to play RTSP in phonegap app by embedding.

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" target="rtsp://someip/video.mp4"/>
```

**Taken from** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/onvif

can some help me how to play a rtsp on phonegap app in certain area

**Note:** same code works in mozilla browser with vlc plugin installed. I dont think we have vlc plugin in phone. So it there plugin in phonegap to fix this ?

Comment: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/rtsp-rtmp-m3ua-streaming - What errors are you getting ?

Comment: There is no answer in this link. I have seen this already. origin i have it as *

Comment: Change the `type="application/x-vlc-plugin"` to `"video/mp4"` ? What ERRORS ARE YOU GETTING?

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: @Pogrindis no luck . I read rstp stream is not supported on phonegap